# How can I look for multiple events in a single cloud function and trigger a schedule query in big query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

This question originated from my earlier post
[How to run a big query schedule query as soon as another big query schedule query has run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66212260/how-to-run-a-big-query-schedule-query-as-soon-as-another-big-query-schedule-quer)

@guillaume blaquiere was kind enough to help me resolve this issue.

However, I have a another requirement where I need to trigger a schedule query once my previous 3 schedule queries are over. So I am going to create pub sub topic for each of the schedule queries and have a cloud function to read these events and trigger another schedule query. However, cloud function can only read one event and not multiple events. Is there a way I can handle this scenario so that my cloud function will read all the 3 events from my 3 previous schedule queries and I trigger new schedule query only once all 3 schedule queries are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously, I should have recommended to you to use Firestore to log the received message, and at each message received (message of the end of scheduled query posted in PubSub) to check if you received all (and continue the process) or not (and stop and wait the next message of end of scheduled query)

However, a new product has been released 6 months ago and it is now Generally Available (GA): [Google Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows)

This product allow you to organise and sequence all your action. To monitor and configure them in a single place. When you have to link several action, it could be a great solution. You can replace your scheduled queries, by a Scheduled Workflow ([trigger the workflow with Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/schedule-workflow)) and then perform your query, wait the end of it, and continue your action (you forget the PubSub messages and so on).

To wait on BigQuery job, you can take inspiration from [an article written by one of my colleague](https://medium.com/codeshake/build-a-serverless-bigquery-ingestion-pipeline-using-cloud-workflows-f893f6b701ee)

---

So, to go back to your question, when you have set up a workflow processing instead of using schedule query, you can imagine triggering several workflow in parallel and wait all the completion with an experimental operator. I just released [an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/parallel-executions-with-google-workflows-3a16f8fee0eb)

Comment: Thank you @guillaume blaquiere. This is awesome and will help a lot of people including me who are looking for something other than cloud composer.  Appreciate you looking into this and providing options to handle this requirement. Thank you again!!